# gazebo(os x 10.9): No valid hardware interface element found in joint

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Dear All,

I am using gazebo and ros-hydro on mac os x 10.9.4. Other than gazebo1.9.x, I installed gazebo2.2 from homebrew. Therefore I built indigo-devel branch gazebo_ros_pkgs, ros_control and ros_controllers.  Gazebo itself works. But when I did a test using rrbot,

```
roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch
```

I got errors as:

```
[ INFO] [1405878912.120519000, 0.271000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [/robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[ERROR] [1405878912.225807000, 0.271000000]: No valid hardware interface element found in joint 'joint1'.
[ERROR] [1405878912.225888000, 0.271000000]: Failed to load joints for transmission 'tran1'.
[ERROR] [1405878912.225932000, 0.271000000]: No valid hardware interface element found in joint 'joint2'.
[ERROR] [1405878912.225956000, 0.271000000]: Failed to load joints for transmission 'tran2'.
```

Then gazebo and robot were shown. I am wondering why gazebo/ros can not find HardwareInterface/EffortJointInterface.

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6654/gazebo(os-x-10.9):-no-valid-hardware-interface-element-found-in-joint/) by [lockandfire](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/903/lockandfire/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-07-20

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok... I found out the reason is that in this version of ros_control/transmission_interface/transimission_parser.cpp , the parser will check if there are  tags in both  section and   section. But in rrbot and other gazebo example, only  has  tag. Therefore this error occurs.

By adding  tags to  section, this error disappears. For example, in rrbot.xacro, change

```
<joint name="joint1"/>
```

as:

```
  <transmission name="tran1">
    <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
    <joint name="joint1">
      <hardwareInterface>EffortJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
    </joint>
  </transmission>
```

---

Originally posted by [lockandfire](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/903/lockandfire/) with karma: 76 on 2014-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2014-07-26**:
Same isseu here ... did you report it somewhere?

**Comment by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) on 2014-08-02**:
I have posted an issue in the ros_control bug tracker: https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/issues/177

**Comment by [lockandfire](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/903/lockandfire/) on 2014-08-08**:
@Arn-O Thank you for reporting

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2015-01-10**:
Fixed by Kei Okada https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_demos/pull/4